# MongoTemplate insert status

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I want to create a DAO where I save users to my database. They should have unique logins and it's a little problematic as mongo db don't have transactions. I have a class with users that looks like this :

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

@Id
private String id;

@Indexed(unique = true)
private String username;

... }
```

and in my DAO I want to save new user

```
mongoTemplate.insert(user);
```

but how can I get the result to send response to my frontend whether user creation was successfull ?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `UserRepository`?

Comment: Do you mean this : public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,String> ?  I used that , but I have no idea how to return error code when saving duplicate and now I try with mongo template

Comment: Well, `extends MongoRepository`, but yes. You have a `unique` index; the repository will throw an exception if you try to save a duplicate.

Comment: I'll read more about that, but they omitted throw exception section in their documentation

Comment: You don't need transactions to handle it - that is first thing. Secondly, mongo has collection level locking (or document if proper engine is used) so there is a level of atomicity. When you have uniquely indexed field, then mongoDb will return an error, which will be propagated by java driver.

Comment: Read the core docs; the exception behavior is common to all the SD implementations. And *just try things*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API will throw `org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException` when unique index is violated.

**Sample Code:-**

```
try {
            mongoOperations.insert(order);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException de) {
            de.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Exception Message when unique index is violated:-**

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: localhost.order index: user_1 dup key: { : \"good\" }" , "code" : 11000}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: localhost.order index: user_1 dup key: { : \"good\" }" , "code" : 11000}
```